# Debugging TFS build process does not stop at breakpoints inside RunOnAgent

Tags: debugging, tfs, build-process

I'm trying to debug a TFS build workflow. The build controller and build agents are local and the build template is configured to use them.
In order to debug I'm attaching the debugger to TFSBuildServiceHost, and trigger (queue) the build.

When I set a breakpoint on the outermost Sequence element, the debugger breaks as expected. It also breaks when I set a breakpoint on the "Run On Agent" block. But when I set a breakpoint on any activity inside "Run On Agent", it doesn't stop there (even though in the log I see that it runs).
Just to make sure, I added a "WriteBuildMessage" activity at the begininning of the "Run On Agent" block to print `Environment.MachineName` and I see that it's the local machine (same as the Controller's).

Note that I want to debug the workflow process and not a particular activity.

In addition, when I hit the breakpoint of the outermost sequence (before "Run On Agent") and press F11 (Step Into) it doesn't stop at the next activity either...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Modifying the build process templates is generally considered a bad idea, especially given that the XAML build system is being deprecated in TFS 2015. You'll be better off doing whatever it is you're trying to do with a PowerShell script and calling that using the Pre/Post-build event hooks in the process template.